# Rudin Theorem 2.41: A set being bounded implies it lives inside some $k$-cell

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the very first line of a theorem in Rudin (the Heine-Borel theorem). The setup is that $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show that if $E$ is closed and bounded, then it is compact. The very first line of Rudin's proof (paraphrased) is that if $E$ is bounded, it lies inside some $k$-cell $I$.

I'm trying unsuccessfully to find his definition of "bounded" in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Based on past knowledge and what he does later in the proof, I believe it means:
$$
\exists M > 0, \; \forall x \in E \subset \mathbb{R}^n, \; |x| < M. 
$$
If this is the correct definition, then it means (using Euclidean distance) that
\begin{align*}
& \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right)^{1/2} < M \\
& \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2 < M^2.
\end{align*}
Looking at the definition of a $k$-cell, I need to show that for every component $x_i$, I have $a_i \leq x_i \leq b_i$ for some $a_i$ and $b_i$. Then $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n [a_i, b_i]$ is the desired $k$-cell. I'm not sure how to deduce that from the above, since I've made only a statement about a sum of the squares of the components.

Comment: To add to @0XLR's concise answer, this problem is asking you to find a box that surrounds a ball. The geometry tells you how to manipulate inequalities; \in $\mathbf{R}^2$, the problem is to find a square that contains a provided disk of radius $r$: to do so, simply pick the square with edge length $2r$. This kind of reasoning generalizes seamlessly to any dimension, and I invite you to ponder why.

Answer (score 5):

For each $i = 1, \ldots, N$, obviously
$$
x_i^2 \leq \sum_{j = 1}^n x_j^2 \leq M^2
$$ i.e. $-M \leq x_i \leq M$ for each $i$. Hence you can just choose the $n$-cell $[-M, M]^n$ in $\mathbb R^n$ to contain $E$.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. My only question is: what if the $x_i$ is negative? Could I instead take, say, the $n$-cell $[\min |x_i|, M]^n$?

Comment: Your answer is essentially correct, but you should have $ -M \leq x_i \leq M$ for each $i$. It's possible that $x_i$ is negative!

Comment: @Cardinality See my comment I posted seconds after yours!

Comment: @William Thank you. So I could choose $[-M,M]^n$. Does the $k$-cell with $\min |x_i|$ also work?

Comment: @Cardinality That is correct, $[-M,M]^n$ works fine! I believe that $[\min |x_i|,M]^n$ has the same problems as $[0,M]^n$; namely, that $\min |x_i|$ is never negative.

Comment: @Cardinality Silly mistake on my part it should indeed be $-M \leq x_i \leq M$. I modified it with the correction.